# Import does not function as bat file; but works in spyder

Tags: numpy, batch-file, installation, pandas-datareader

I am still not the most sophisticated python user; but I cannot overcome this probably simple problem. I have a code that works perfectly with the spyder interface. I would like to make it a recurring task via creating a bat file. The bat file which in turn triggers a cmd interface does not import pandas_data reader and the code gets stuck and aborts.

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
```

this line above creates the error below. It's a lengthy text.

```
File "C:\Users\myself\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .data import (   File "C:\Users\myself\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pandas.util._decorators import deprecate_kwarg   File "C:\Users\myself\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Unable to import required dependencies:\n" + "\n".join(missing_dependencies) ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies: numpy:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.
- Try uninstalling and reinstalling numpy.
- If you have already done that, then:
  1. Check that you expected to use Python3.7 from "C:\Users\myself\anaconda3\python.exe",
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy version "1.17.0" you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.
```

Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.

Original error was: `DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

Comment: I am confused if this was a Question or Answer.

Comment: well I edited the question a bit. The confusing thing is the whole lengthy text is the error message itself.